# Trouble with the showkeys package

Tags: equations, formatting, numbering

I am using `showkeys` package in LaTeX so my labels inside `\[ \]` math statements  show up. Usually  `\[ \]` does not show any numbering, I both want to use `\[ \]`, and numbering, this was the only solution I could find.

In any case, with `showkeys`, the label numbers show up in little squares. Is there a way to change that square into parens, or maybe brackets?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

It is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: The standard ways to number equations is to put them into an `\begin{equation} ... \end{equation}` environment.  The `showkeys` package is for debugging purposes (or drafts) only. Maybe you should read some of the sources mentioned in the [`mathmode`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/tags/mathmode/info) tag wiki.

Comment: If you register your account you should be able to add comments. Can we ask *why* you want to do this?

Comment: ok it works now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want equation numbering use:

```
\begin{equation} 
    e = m c^2
\end{equation}
```

Using `equation*` (which requires `amsmath` package) instead will disable the equation numbering.

To adjust the appearance of the label from the `showkeys`, you can redefine the `\showkeyslabelformat` macro:

```
\renewcommand*\showkeyslabelformat[1]{\normalfont\small\ttfamily(#1)}
```

Comment: `equation*` is available only when **amsmath** has been loaded.

Comment: @egreg: Thanks. Have added that. I really should follow my own advice and not post code snippets!! :-)

Comment: \\renewcommand worked.

Comment: @user423805 Don't use showkeys for numbering equations. It's for a completely different purpose.

Comment: @egreg i figured as much.. here is what I need tho: I want to use \\[ \\] for all my equations. If I place a label in a \\[ \\], I want it to start showing numbers. is this possible?

Comment: @user423805 For having an automatic number you've to use `\begin{equation}...\end{equation}`. If you load **amsmath**, then `\tag{...}` inserts a "handmade" number also in `\[...\]`.

Comment: That worked -- with one downside, inclusion of amsmath  messed up the spacing I worked hard to get right. Example tex file and pdf is here http://goo.gl/HYr5F . After I included amsmath topmargin spacing was ignored for some reason. My settings makes everything left aligned, no paragraph spacing, same single line vertical space between equations, paragraphs.

Comment: @user423805: Please post a separate question and provide a minimal compilable example to illustrate the specific problem.

Comment: Just did, right here - http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36604/amsmath-spacing-left-alignment