# Amsmath, spacing, left alignment

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, equations, amsmath

It was recommended that I include `amsmath` package to use `\tag{}` (which works). When I do this however, it somehow changes my predefined spacing; I would like everything to be left aligned, no left spacing for beginning of paragraphs,  single line space between all equations, all paragraphs.

Sample code below; if you comment out `amsmath` line, you'll see the output I was aiming for. My question is what additional commands do I use for `amsmath` to this kind of output?

```
\documentclass[12pt,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[latin5]{inputenc}
\usepackage{color}
\setlength{\parskip}{8pt}
\setlength{\parsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\headsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\topskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0pt}
\setlength{\topsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\partopsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\mathindent}{0cm}

\begin{document}

Some line 

\[ y = x^2 \]

Another line

\[ y = x^2  \]

\[ y = x^2 \]

One more line

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have mentioned you really should not be doing this.  That being said, the code below provides a ***hack*** of the `equation*` environment which is what `\[ ... \]` construct becomes after you load `amsmath`.  I am not able to see any difference in your MWE's output with `amsmath` loaded and this hack applied.  No guarantee that there won't be other cases where the results with `amsmath` will vary though.

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{equation*}{\vspace{\dimexpr -2\baselineskip+2.5pt\relax}\belowdisplayskip=0pt%
  \mathdisplay@push
  \st@rredtrue \global\@eqnswfalse
  \mathdisplay{equation*}%
}{%
  \endmathdisplay{equation*}%
  \mathdisplay@pop
  \ignorespacesafterend%
}
\makeatother
```

Answer (score 9):

You must *never* have blank lines above a displayed equation (unless it really starts a paragraph, which is bad style anyway); a blank line below can be used, but only if the equation ends a paragraph.

For consecutive displayed equations use the `gather*` environment.

```
\documentclass[12pt,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage[latin5]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\setlength{\parskip}{8pt}
\setlength{\parsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\headsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\topskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0pt}
\setlength{\topsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\partopsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\mathindent}{0cm}

\begin{document}

Some line 
\[
y = x^2
\]
Another line
\begin{gather*}
y = x^2\\
y = x^2
\end{gather*}
One more line

\end{document}
```

Comment: No this wont work. I want to use \\[ \\] exactly the way I've shown you. These extra {gather*} statements are clouding up the text.

Comment: Then you can't have what you want. That's it.

Comment: @user423805: If the eventual *output* is what you're after, then sometimes there may be a compromise in terms of the *input*.

Comment: @user423805: You can use `%` to comment out blank lines

Comment: @cmhughes -- commenting out blank lines is a great idea, but it's still bad form to have multiple consecutive separate equations.  it will result in really poor vertical spacing.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: agreed